# I restarted my computer and Android studio is not shutting down or quitting app

Tags: android-studio

I tried quitting through terminal it didn't work. I tried restarting my computer android seems to be stuck in a position. I had errors before this app got stuck/froze. My computer works it is just the app that is not working anymore. I cannot quit and re open app and I tried using finder and force quit through there but that didn't work. I also am not sure what else to do, I can still use  other apps and they work really well. I wanted to download android studio again so I dragged the app to trash. It isn't letting me drag it to trash because the app is open. Since I can't use it I cannot do anything. Has anyone had this problem? Can anyone help me?  (I am using a MAC)

Comment: I've had this same issues on Mac with Android Studio whenever any tasks were being done (gradle sync, indexing, etc) or if I had the emulator open. However using the Apple menu (top left) and doing Force Quit... would work for me.

Comment: Yes I tried doing that. It didn't work. Mine also had a problem with gradle sync, and indexing before the app froze. I just restarted like for the fifth time and it is still running. I am going to try shutting it down.

Comment: So I unplugged my computer for a long time and then plugged it in the power outlet and I guess when it started off again it deleted Android Studio. Hope I help other  people having the same problem in the future. This was wierd.

Comment: Thank You @MateuszSiniarski